# Error adding sceneform 1.16 that it cannot be resolved

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I followed:
https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk

and added

```
Finally, add a reference to the Sceneform SDK to your app's build.gradle:
dependencies {
    api project(":sceneformux")
}
```

But I am getting Error

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :sceneformux.
```

am I missing anything .

After following the steps I am also getting Error that the following are not present.

```
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.math.Quaternion;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.math.Vector3;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your Android Studio cannot find the sceneformux module.

You add this to your project as outlined in the steps at the link you shared - in particular:

1. Download sceneform-android-sdk-1.16.0.zip from the Sceneform SDK releases page.
2. Extract the sceneformsrc and sceneformux directories into your project's top-level directory. The resulting directory structure should be similar to the following:

> project
> +-- app
> +-- build.gradle
> +-- ...
> +-- sceneformsrc
> +-- sceneformux
> +-- build.gradle
> +-- settings.gradle
> +-- ...

3. Modify your project's settings.gradle to include the Sceneform projects:
   include ':app'

> // Add these lines:
> include ':sceneform'
> project(':sceneform').projectDir=new File('sceneformsrc/sceneform')
>
> include ':sceneformux'
> project(':sceneformux').projectDir=new File('sceneformux/ux')

4. Finally, add a reference to the Sceneform SDK to your app's build.gradle:
   dependencies {
   api project(":sceneformux")
   }

Assuming you did all the above, then it may be just that Android studio has not synched to fully recognise the directories you copied into the project, sceneformsrc and sceneformux.

You most likely have resolved this by now, but for completeness, I saw something similar and, while there are likely more precise synch options in Android Studio to fix this, I find that quitting Android Studio and restarting it usually clears this type of issue, and did for me in this case also.